# Why is my C code not generating random numbers within the range I set?

Tags: c

I was playing around with functions to get familiar with C, since I'm new to it. I was trying to generate a random number between 5 and 10 (inclusively). It's not working as intended.

**CODE SOURCE**

```
int randomInt(int maximum,int minimum)
{
  return(rand() % maximum + minimum);
}
```

**SAMPLE INPUT**

```
int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
        printf("NUMBER IS %d \n", randomInt(10,5));
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT (INCORRECT)**

```
// NUMBER IS 10 
// NUMBER IS 8 
// NUMBER IS 11 
// NUMBER IS 7 
// NUMBER IS 6 
// NUMBER IS 9 
// NUMBER IS 14 
// NUMBER IS 5 
// NUMBER IS 7 
// NUMBER IS 11 
// NUMBER IS 11 
// NUMBER IS 12 
// NUMBER IS 12 
// NUMBER IS 7 
// NUMBER IS 6 
// NUMBER IS 12 
// NUMBER IS 5 
// NUMBER IS 10 
// NUMBER IS 7 
// NUMBER IS 13 
// NUMBER IS 14
```

It's not giving me the random generated numbers between 5 and 10(inclusively)

Comment: should be % (maximum - minimun), shouldnt it?

Comment: Aside: never question if the library is ***busted*** as the first response ;) Almost always it is "why am I not using the library function correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int randomInt(int maximum,int minimum)
{
  return(rand() % maximum + minimum);
}
```

Calling `randomInt(10,5)` will generate a random integer in the range `0 -> 9` (`rand() % maximum`) and then add `5` to it, resulting in a minimum of `5` and a maximum of `14`.

What you want to do to generate a random value between `min` and `max` is to generate a random value in the range `0 -> (max-min)` first, then add `min` to it. This will make the minimum output `0 + min = min` and the maximum output `max - min + min = max`, which is exactly what you want.

So this is the correct code:

```
int randomInt(int maximum,int minimum)
{
  return(rand() % (maximum - minimum + 1) + minimum);
}
```

Comment: It still doesnt include 10 tho, it goes up to 9 only.

Comment: @decentProgrammer I made a typo, I fixed it now.

Comment: that said, using % does not keep the fair distribution (but here, I guess this is not really a concern, just in case of...)